# Make a retry screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift4, nsurlsession

So I have currently 2 viewcontroller which are making service calls to server.
I want to handle the failure by adding a view/vc( containing an error message and retry button).

I can add two views seperately and call the services again on retry button tap.
But just want to know is there any other method to solve this problem in a efficient way.

```
postRequest(with: URLString.jobDetails!, parameter: parameter){(result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                switch error {
              print("show retry screen which will make same url call again on tapping the button")
                }
            case .success(let data):
                self.jobDetailList = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                self.renderDecodedData(jobDetailList: self.jobDetailList)
            }
```

Comment: Create UIView subclass and add its instance in both view controllers. Use delegate for retry button actions

Comment: Show an alertview with 2 buttons, "Retry" and "Cancel". If user clicks on retry call the same postRequest and in the other case dismiss the alertview